# Android Flurry Ads Fetch error

Tags: android, ads, flurry

I am integrating [Flurry ads](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/) in my Android app. I followed all instructions from their site, but I get `Fetch error`, `code 20` every time it tries to load ad (both interstitial and banner).

Comment: Code 20 indicates there is no ad to fill your request. What is your geographic location? Also what is the location of your intended audience?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it could be fill. I am from Serbia.

Comment: @filipst Same problem for me & others too. No solution found so far and even flurry guys don't revert to the mails sent to their support team nor they reply at SO. If you found any solution somehow then please add an answer to your own question.

Comment: @FlurrySupport I'm getting same error. I am from India. In which locations the add will show

Comment: This error indicates that Flurry's RTB networks do not have any advertisements to fill the fetch requests in your geographic location. If you plan to release the app in a different locale you can test the functionality by VPN to that location.